# How to view entire call stack hierarchy without breakpoints? (Visual Studio 2015 + ASP.NET Web Forms)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, webforms

I want to figure out what methods are being called in what order when I build and run an ASP.NET web form application.

The context is that I'm trying to decipher the architecture of the code base I'm working on, and its not clear where the program begins. Using breakpoints randomly has been helpful but does not give the entire picture.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [Runtime Flow](https://vlasovstudio.com/runtime-flow/) extension to view entire method calls hierarchy of an ASP.NET applicaton.