# How to get the runtime call stack of an external ASP.Net web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reflection, runtime

So basically running an external web application and listen/monitor its method invocations.

Is there a way to do that in .Net? ...Get the runtime call stack of that application?

TIA!

Comment: what do you mean with external application? you can do remote debugging or create a `new StackTrace();` in your application

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489396/how-to-view-entire-call-stack-hierarchy-without-breakpoints-visual-studio-2015